# Visual Studio Sequential Workflow : spexception was unhandled by user code

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I have created simple **sequential workflow** in visual studio with one **application page**(which has 3 buttons like Approve,Reject & Close buttons) for editing the task. i deployed it to site collection on (http://8888).it works as i want.

but when i deployed it to other site collection eg (http://8888/sites/mysite) then the **Taskitem.Update()** line throw an error,

I have also created two same lists (Request List and Task List with same name and fields) on : //8888/sites/mysite

```
protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            string siteurl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url.ToString();
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteurl))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {                        
                    if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != string.Empty && Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;                            
                        SPList Tasklist = web.Lists["MyWorkflowTasks"];
                        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
                        SPListItem Taskitem= Tasklist .GetItemById(id);                            
                        Taskitem["Status"] = "Completed";
                        Taskitem["RequestStatus"] = "Approved";
                        Taskitem.Update();// this line throw error : spexception was unhandled by user code 
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;                            
                        this.Context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Remember above code works fine on my first site collection but not on other as described above.

can anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure the task with ID which you are passing exists in `mysite` ?

Comment: yes, this task item is exist in my Task list. and while debugging i also able to see its all fields and values by QuickWatch.